# Laravel not saving decimal numbers

Tags: mysql, laravel

Having issue with Laravel 5.3, PHP 7.2 and a currency field.

This is my migration script,  i changed the amount field to decimal too but doesnt work.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('order_details', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('id', true);
        $table->integer('order_id');
        $table->string('product_id', 15);
        $table->string('unit', 10);
        $table->double('price', 10,2)->default(0.00);
        $table->double('quantity', 10, 2)->default(0);
        $table->double('amount', 18,2)->default(0.00);


        $table->double('sup_price',10,2)->default(0.00);
        $table->double('sup_quantity',4,2)->default(0);
        $table->double('sup_amount',18,2)->default(0.00);
    });
}
```

in my controller I have hardcoded the value

```
$modelName->amount = 24.87;
$modelName->save();
```

When I looked into the DB it is just storing 24.

What could be wrong with it. Thanks

Comment: Please do `show create table your_table_name` in MySQL and include the output in your question.

Comment: Also, please note that tweaking an already-ran migration file won't apply those changes to the database. You'd have to roll back and re-migrate if you change it.

Answer (score 2):

try with this:

```
$modelName->amount = number_format(24.87, 2, '.', '');
```

This works for m